# What’s “quantum” about Schrödinger’s Cat?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedingers-cat

In the famous Schrödinger's cat thought experiment, the cat is proposed to exist in a superposition of alive and dead states until observed.

A radioactive atom's decay triggers the release of a poison that determines the cat's fate.

Is the radioactive decay an *essential* component for obtaining a superposition, or could a "non-quantum" mechanism achieve the same effect?

I was always under the impression that any random, macroscopic phenomenon we don't measure (like tossing a coin) would be sufficient to trigger the poison.

Comment: Like the radioactive decay involved in the experiment?

Comment: Here is more on Schrodinger's Cat. It has a good answer to your question, and then continues on to show why the Everett interpretation (Many Worlds) is a good alternative to Copenhagen. [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTXTPe3wahc)

Comment: Classical objects Linked with quantum phenomenon: the cat's survival is linked with a quantum poison which is in a superposition of  being released and not released. Hence cat behaves like being dead and alive at the same time. So a classical object is behaving like a quantum object.

Comment: Edited question to add clarity.

Comment: I've always maintained Schrödinger's cat is a red herring

Comment: The ensemble interpretation has no difficulty with Schrödingers cat.

Answer (score 4):

The Copenhagen interpretation sets up two different processes: a unitary, reversible process that is being described by e.g. the Schroedinger equation and a non-unitary irreversible process that can be described by the Born rule ("the measurement"). The measurement process, at the time, was imagined to be facilitated by a macroscopic system (e.g. the radiation detector and in this case its extension "the cat").

The argument goes that by moving the internal details of the measurement system ("the cat") into the unitary reversible part of the dynamical description we can invalidate the ontology of the Copenhagen interpretation. On its face this is plausible since the division between the quantum mechanical system and the "classical" measurement system is an arbitrary human choice.

This runs into a number of logical problems that do not make Schroedinger's cat a good model system for the quantum/classical transition.

The first problem is that Copenhagen does not actually describe a single box with a single cat in it and it does not make actual classical predictions about them. It only describes an infinite ensemble of boxes with cats. Nowhere does the formalism tell us anything about any particular cat, i.e. it can not and does not actually produce a "this cat is dead" prediction. It only tells us that if we had an infinite number of boxes and we would open them at later and later times, the chances of finding the cats (plural, not singular) alive would decrease exponentially (or at least almost exponentially, see below).

The second problem is that the crucial property of "the measurement process" is not impacted by the system boundary choice. A measurement is irreversible by definition because it has to leave a lasting record. Such a record simply does not exist until it is actually created, but by stipulating that the boxes remain closed, Schroedinger's cat eliminates the possibility of an actual measurement. We may imagine that their contents are either alive or dead cats, but that is mere imagination. It is not an actual physical reduction of the potentiality of the unitary process quantum mechanical process of the ensemble to the certainty of the individual frequentist measurement.

A more thorough analysis of what is happening with the quantum mechanical part of the box confirms that Schroedinger's mental model of such a system was flawed in addition. Let's strip the experiment down to just one exited atom in a perfectly closed box with mirror walls. The quantum mechanical state of this system can be described by the superposition of

|excited atom>|electromagnetic field in ground state> and
|atom in ground state>|one photon in em field>.

Since we assume that the mirrored box has a much larger volume than the atom, the single photon state is actually a superposition of many different modes. As a consequence the probability distribution is heavily skewed towards finding a de-exited atom and a single photon in the box rather than an excited atom and no photon. But once in a while that atom has to absorb that photon again and go back into its excited state. So no matter when we open the box, there is always a non-zero probability for finding the atom in the original state. In other words, the exponential decay solution is merely an incorrect ad-hoc assumption. This probability can be extremely small, of course, if the phase space of the photon state, or the phase space of the "cat object" are large, but it can never be zero.

In other words, the setup does not even lead to an absolutely dead cat. It leads to the strange phenomenon that we should be able to find an alive cat in this box even after an infinite amount of time. In classical mechanics this is known as the Poincare recurrence theorem. It is just as nonsensical in that scenario as it is in quantum mechanics, of course, but that is the nature of poor approximations... they do not predict what we would expect. The erroneous assumption here is that completely closed systems exist. In reality they do not exist. There is always leakage of energy to and from the environment and that is what actually destroys the quantum mechanical state. Schroedinger tried to evade the consequences of weak measurements on a quantum mechanical system which do, indeed, lead to "decoherence" and to classical outcomes. One could argue that he couldn't have been aware of "decoherence" since this was only proposed later, but that is science historically not true. At the time of Schroedinger's failed proposal other people, including Heisenberg and even more so Mott had already thought about the consequences of frequent measurements. Schroedinger may not have known about those ideas or maybe he just didn't take them seriously. In hindsight it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Answering [v1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/797853/1)

The intent of [Schrodinger' s cat](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat#:%7E:text=Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s%20cat%20is%20a%20thought,is%20both%20alive%20and%20dead.) was to show the absurdity of considering a quantum state of a macroscopic system. Even then, the quantum part you are asking for was the presence of radioactive decay in the original statement of the experiment.

> One can even set up quite ridiculous cases. A cat is locked up in a steel chamber, along with the following device (which must be secured against direct interference by the cat): in a Geiger counter, there is a tiny bit of radioactive substance, so small, that perhaps in the course of an hour only one of the atoms decays, but also, with equal probability, perhaps none; if it happens, the counter tube discharges and through a relay releases a hammer that shatters a small flask of hydrocyanic acid. If one has left this entire system to itself for an hour, one would say that the cat still lives if meanwhile no atom has decayed. The psi-function of the entire system would express this by having in it the living and dead cat (pardon the expression) mixed or smeared out in equal parts.
>
> It is typical of these cases that an indeterminacy originally restricted to the atomic domain becomes transformed into macroscopic indeterminacy, which can then be resolved by direct observation. That prevents us from so naively accepting as valid a "blurred model" for representing reality. In itself, it would not embody anything unclear or contradictory. There is a difference between a shaky or out-of-focus photo and a snapshot of clouds and fog banks.

Answer (score 1):

Schrödinger’s cat is a thought experiment that makes us think about the following. If we are happy that nuclear-level events such as radioactive decay can be described by quantum mechanics, yet these events can be connected causally to a macroscopic event such as the death of a cat, which we do *not* think is described by quantum mechanics, then at what stage in the causal chain is the quantum mechanical description replaced the "everyday" description ? Is this a step change ? Or is it a gradual replacement ? Or is there no replacement at all, and it is only our limited perceptions that make us think the cat is governed by different physics than the radioactive nucleus ?

Answer (score 1):

> What’s “quantum” about Schrödinger’s cat?

This is an important question. If find that popular physics accounts do not explain this enough. The usual account is something of the sort:

> a classical cat is either death or alive, Schrödinger's cat is kinda of both (superposition) until you open the box.

You can accept this, but a classical physicists from the time would ask how do you know? What difference does that make? How is that different from a classical coin tossing?

If this is your question, then the answer is it is No. There is no experiment you can make to the difference between Schrödinger's cat and a real cat that dies or not from a coin toss. A single particle/cat superposition can be efficiently simulated by a classical coin toss. You need interference or entangled states in order to see a clear difference with classical physics.

Now back to your questions:

> This is not true of a cat, so do we expect quantum ideas to apply to macroscopic cats also?

This question can be easily reverted, the whole elementary nature of the world is quantum why wouldn't it be possible to make a cat into a superposition? Obviously we never see this in macroscopic phenomena! That was the point of this thought experiment. It was not made to clarify quantum phenomena but to contest it.

> is the Copenhagen interpretation necessarily applying to all phenomenon, or just the very smallest where the “effects” become significant?

Copenhague interpretation is agnostic. Some of its adherents considered that there should be a [Heisenberg cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_cut) a scale where it stops. However nobody has been unable to find or clearly define such a scale.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum mechanics has equations of motion like the Schrodinger equation that are linear. If you have an radioactive atom that could have decayed with state $|d\rangle$ or it may not have decayed with state $|u\rangle$, then the state $|\psi\rangle=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u\rangle+|d\rangle)$ is also a solution. This is an example of a property called linearity.

Now suppose that you have a cat in a box with an atom in the state $|\psi\rangle$ and a measurement device measures it and breaks a poison vial killing the cat if the atom has decayed. If you apply quantum mechanics to the measurement device $M$ and the cat $C$ as well as the atom $A$, then the state becomes
$$\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u\rangle_A|u\rangle_D|alive\rangle_C+|d\rangle_A|d\rangle_D|dead\rangle_C)$$
So then it looks like the cat is alive and dead at the same time and since we only see a live cat or a dead cat, something is wrong with our understanding of this situation.

You might try to say quantum mechanics only applies to small systems like atoms, but that has some problems. You might say that the equations of fluid mechanics don't apply to a brick, but there is an explanation of why it wouldn't apply to the brick. The Schrodinger equation (or another equation that have the same linearity property) decribes atoms, electrons, protons and all their interactions so it should describe an entire cat too. People have tried to modify quantum theory in various ways to eliminate this effect by explicitly changing the equation of motion, such as collapse theories or pilot wave theories

https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969

https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10761

These theories have problems like being non-local.

Other physicists just ignore the problem. This is commonly called the Copenhagen or statistical interpretation of quantum mechanics.

If you apply quantum mechanics consistently to the cat and everything else, then there is a relevant effect called decoherence. In quantum mechanics the different versions of an atom or other particle can interfere with one another and this is required to explain the existence of atoms and stuff like that. But if you measure a system while it's undergoing interference and so copy information out of that system that suppresses interference and this effect is called decoherence. A cat is a large hot squidgy thing and is constantly interacting with the air, photons, the ground etc. so it is pretty thoroughly decohered and interference between the different versions of the cat doesn't happen. The same is true of any object large enough for you to see, including you. So if you don't modify quantum mechanics there are multiple versions of all these systems but you only see one at a time because of decoherence

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

In this view of quantum mechanics the existence of multiple versions of macroscopic objects can still be relevant to explaining experimental outcomes, e.g. - in entanglement experiments:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328